# How to update the database once when the timer expires?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using an ASP.NET web form and I have two fields `Start_date` and `End_date` in it.

I want to update a particular field in SQLServer once when the time goes beyond the `End_date` (i.e. the deadline is expired).

e.g. if the `End_date` is on 06/09/2015, then the SQLServer field should be updated as `Expired` at 12.01 AM on 06/10/2015.

I am new to ASP.NET and please let me know if you have any ideas. Thank you

Comment: @user3546066 I don't have any idea how to update in database. I have created the form using C# and the field values are saved in SQLServer columns. I work on a insurance project and once when the end-date is expired it should be updated as "Expired" in the DB. There is a field called "Insurance Status" in my DB and it should be updated in it.

Comment: If all you are doing is updating a column to `Expired` I would not go that route. I would make that `Insurace Status` field calculated, either calculated in in your code before it is displayed to the user or as a calculated database field.

Answer (score 2):

There are way too many ways to do such thing. I.e:

- making a SQL script that does that and adding that script as scheduled job in SqlServer
- or, creating a WindowsService that sleeps and wakes up every hour or six and checks for expired records
- or, adding a module like Hangfire to your ASP application and adding such scheduled task there
- ..

Those three are probably the most often used.

Anyways, it's always about some scheduler and some job to do periodicaly. Think how to write one "run" of the job (find expired, mark/delete them), then read about what schedulers you can use, then glue it together and configure the scheduler and done.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, but if all you need to do is make database changes at a given time, then I recommend using the [SQL Server Agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms189237.aspx). You can set it up to run just once or on a recurring schedule and you can set it up to run a stored procedure or you can feed it straight SQL commands.